# How to ignore escaped elements in a "rule" (regular expression)?

Tags: regex, language-agnostic

I'm trying to do with regex (regular expression), for example (if using javascript):

```
var str = '[abc\[0123\]] [efg\[987\]h] [Hello \[world\]!] [foo [baz]]';
str.match(/\[(.*?)\]/g);
```

> Output: `["[abc[0123]", "[efg[987]h", "[Hello [world]!", "[foo [baz]"]`

Or

```
var str = '{abc\{0123\}} {efg\{987\}h} {Hello \{world\}!} {foo {baz}}';
str.match(/\{(.*?)\}/g);
```

> Output: `["{abc{0123}", "{efg{987}", "{Hello {world}", "{foo {baz}"]`

But I need you ignore the first items not escaped as `[foo [baz]]` and caught only `[baz]` and others that have been escaped as well:

```
 ["[abc[0123]]", "[efg[987]h]", "[Hello [world]!]", "[baz]"]
```

And second example returns:

```
 {"{abc{0123}}", "{efg{987}h}", "{Hello {world}!}", "{baz}"]
```

My intention initially is to study, but also plan to use in such things as a structure that is similar to CSS selectors:

- For example:

  ```
  input[name=\[0\]], input[name=foo\[baz\]\[bar\]]
  ```

  Returns:

  ```
  [0], [1]
  ```
- And map of URLs I plan to create:

  ```
  /{name}/{foo\{bar}/{baz\{foo\}}/
  ```

  Returns:

  ```
  {name}, {foo{bar}, {baz{foo}}
  ```

What I want is to ignore the characters escaped into the rule, how can I do this? Can provide an example in any language, the most important is the Regex

Comment: I guess you meant `var str = '[abc\\[0123\\]] [efg\\[987\\]h] [Hello \\[world\\]!] [foo [baz]]';`. Then, if you want to match escaped `]` and `[`, use [`\[[^\[\]\\]*(?:\\.[^\[\]\\]*)*\]`](https://regex101.com/r/zO1vP4/1). Note it won't match `[foo [baz]]` as the inside brackets are not escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not (and can't) do balanced text, the best you could do is account
for escape-escape or escape-brackets.
Note that I didn't include the unrolled version of these regexes because these
require a body.

(Substitute `{}` as needed).

*The first closure*

`\[(?:\\[\\\[\]]|[^\]])+\]`

Expanded

```
 \[
 (?:
      \\ [\\\[\]] 
   |  
      [^\]] 
 )+
 \]
```

*The absolute inner braces*

`\[(?:\\[\\\[\]]|[^\[\]])+\]`

Expanded

```
 \[
 (?:
      \\ [\\\[\]] 
   |  
      [^\[\]] 
 )+
 \]
```